# delphi 7. How to check whether the unit file exists and add it with (directives?) to compile with the project

Tags: delphi

I have a unit which is the part of several modules(dll, applications).

In some of them I need to use in that module their classes.

Is it possible to use compiler directives (or other methods) to include the unit to the file in case it is included in the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the answer is yes. You can use a conditional define in the uses clause:

```
uses
{$IFDEF USE_MYSTUFF}
  MyUnit,
{$ENDIF}
  Classes, Windows;
```

and then define (or not) a conditional define `USE_MYSTUFF` in the project options.

See also [`$IFDEF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IFDEF_directive_%28Delphi%29), [`$DEFINE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DEFINE_directive_%28Delphi%29) and [`$INCLUDE`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Include_file_%28Delphi%29) directives and [Conditional Compilation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: yes it is some kind of an option. But isn't there any way (maybe not with the directives) to conditionally add module to uses list? WIthout setting project's scope directives?

Comment: You can also use the directive `{$DEFINE USE_MYSTUFF}` in a unit. You can also put your directives into a separate file (or different files with different directives) and include it with the directive `{$INCLUDE mystuff.inc}`. Which specific file gets included would depend on the search path.

Comment: Thanks I will probably use the optionwith the INC file. There is no way to check if the inc file exists prior to load it?

Comment: Or cannot I retrieve the project name and compare it or something ..?

Comment: No, the included file has to exist, otherwise you get a compiler error. But you could have several versions of it in different directories and selectively include one of them by changing the project's search path, for example.

Comment: ehh ok, I will probably create global conditional define, otherwise I would have to place in every project the inc file. Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome. I also think global conditional define is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I found an easier solution. I have just extracted the classes which make use of this additional unit to a new file. And this file included in this project. Now is ok . :)

Comment: @John: This sounds like a **much** better option then mucking around with conditional compilation etc.